# WSO2 ESB API payload Security

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I developed some API in WSO2 ESB server.I need to pass encrypted data to my resource server through the ESB. But i need to update  data (payload) while request reach in ESB apart of my business.Is there any solution .any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the requirement you have mentioned here you can update data in the payload inside the ESB with the help of a Payload Factory mediator. 
As an example, please refer documentation [1] Section of “Using WSO2 ESB to modify messages with text content".

Encrypting the data/payload inside the WSO2 ESB, does not support Out Of the Box. 
As a suggestion, I would suggest to implement the scenario with the help of the transport layer by Enabling SSL profiling feature with WSO2 ESB which will communicate with a resource server in a safe manner.

For more information on SSL profiles in WSO2 ESB, please visit documentation [2].

[1] https://nadeesha678.wordpress.com/tag/wso2-esb/ 
[2] http://pathberiya.blogspot.com/2010/07/ssl-profiles-in-wso2-esb.html